# Change permalinks for posts but not for custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, theme-development, permalinks, mod-rewrite

Currently my permalink structure for posts is

```
domain.com/post-title
```

I'm using a static front page and a "blog" page for posts. I'd like to to change the permalink structure for posts, tags and categories to

```
domain.com/blog/post-title
```

I can easily add /blog/ in the permalink structure but the catch is that my custom post types also get this modified permalink structure and that is not the desired result.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you [register your post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), the `with_front` argument of `rewrite` should be `false`, so the permastruct is not appended to the front of your custom post type permalink.

```
$args = array(
    // snip...
    'rewrite' => array( 'with_front' => false ),
    // snip...
); 

register_post_type( 'your-post-type', $args );
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That did indeed seem to solve the problem. I wonder though, don't you think it's quite strange that WordPress doesn't include /blog/ by default if you're using a static front page and a posts page "blog"?

Are there any advantages of using the permalink structure without the /blog/ ?

Comment: Thank you, this answer helped me to find where to change the needed option using the CPTUI plugin.