# custom permalink for post only not custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins

hi like state on the title , how can i achieve this ?
i've try lots of plugins and its all only work with custom post types only.

so here is the situation , i have a custom post types (food) , and for the recipes i use wordpress posts ,

and i want to make the post permalinks become /recipes/my-awesome-title for old and new post.
i know i can change this in permalink section but if i add /recipes/%postname/ ,

my custom post also become /recipes/food/my-awesome-title and that is not what i want.

i dont try any code yet except install couple of plugins since i can do codes in wp and depends on plugins instead.

according to this [a link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83516/change-permalinks-for-posts-but-not-for-custom-post-types) i have to register post type which i have no idea at all how to do that , please help me for those who capable of , thank you before for your kindness.

edited:
i found this snippets

```
function filter_post_link($permalink, $post) {
    if ($post->post_type != 'post')
        return $permalink;
    return 'recipes'.$permalink;
}
add_filter('pre_post_link', 'filter_post_link', 10, 2);
```

my post becomes /recipes/my-awesome-post but i got redirect loop redirected you too many times.

any idea why ? i have also update my permalink

Comment: How do you register the food cpt? Did you set the `with_front` argument?

Comment: hi , dont need to register anything . just use the code on my answered below

Comment: The code in your answer is not necessary if you register the `food` custom post type with the correct arguments.

Answer (score 1):

ok so after searching again i found this and it worked

```
/**
 * Add new rewrite rule
 */
function create_new_url_querystring() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'recipes/([^/]*)$',
        'index.php?name=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
    add_rewrite_tag('%recipes%','([^/]*)');
}
add_action('init', 'create_new_url_querystring', 999 );
/**
 * Modify post link
 * This will print /recipes/post-name instead of /post-name
 */
function append_query_string( $url, $post, $leavename ) {
    if ( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {     
        $url = home_url( user_trailingslashit( "recipes/$post->post_name" ) );
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'post_link', 'append_query_string', 10, 3 );
/**
 * Redirect all posts to new url
 * If you get error 'Too many redirects' or 'Redirect loop', then delete everything below
 */
function redirect_old_urls() {
    if ( is_singular('post') ) {
        global $post;
        if ( strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/recipes/') === false) {
           wp_redirect( home_url( user_trailingslashit( "recipes/$post->post_name" ) ), 301 );
           exit();
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_old_urls' );
```

link to the full post can be found [a link](https://www.bobz.co/add-blog-prefix-permalink-structure-blog-posts/) here.